# Can a parliament pass laws that constrain the scope of future legislation?

Tags: parliament, legislation

For example, can a parliament pass a law that says: "*Any future budget bill must contain a section that explains the estimated carbon emission this spending may lead to in the next 10 years.*"

In theory, a parliament can enact such a law and then later pass a budget bill without complying with said law because it is not obligated to hold itself to account.

But then again, it seems necessary that there are times when parliament needs these "meta legislation" that defines the framework in which they can make laws in an orderly manner.

Question: Can a parliament pass laws that constrain the scope of future legislation? What happens if a parliament passes a law that inadvertently contradicts the requirement of a previous law?

Comment: There isn't a general answer. It depends upon the constitution of a particular country with a parliament. Some countries allow this in the form of treaties or with supermajority legislation, others do not.

Comment: Changes/amendments to the constitution are the common approach if parliaments really want to do this. See [balanced budget amendements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_budget_amendment) in several countries as an example.

Comment: In the UK at least, it's perfectly valid to pass such a law, and it is indeed binding - until a future parliament chooses to pass another law removing it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman .. although there is the interesting precedent of the (English) Treason Act 1540, which contains a clause 'It shall be high treason for any person, by word or deed, ... to procure or do any thing to the repeal of this act'.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I think the point of the question is that if the parliament can simply not follow a law when it wants to, then it isn't binding. If it were going to follow the law anyways then it would be useless, if they didn't want to follow the law they would simply pass a law overruling it and then it would also be useless.

Comment: More specifically, I would be interested if there would be any way to mandate "Any future budget bill must contain a section that explains the estimated carbon emission this spending may lead to in the next 10 years." in the US short of through the obviously arduous process of constitutional amendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Westminster-style parliament may indeed enact a scheme to **entrench** at a constitutional level certain overarching statutory requirements, perhaps like the carbon emissions requirement you propose.  Under the Diceyan principle of **continuing sovereignty** it can’t entrench this sort of thing so deeply that it may *never* be changed, but it can impose on future parliaments manner and form obligations (such as a requirement for a two-thirds majority) that need to be dealt with before the entrenched provision can be repealed or amended.

For example, many parliaments have entrenched provisions akin to a “Bill of Rights” with overarching requirements concerning legislation seeking to limit certain rights.

> What happens if a parliament passes a law that inadvertently contradicts the requirement of a previous law?

Normally the most recent law will be understood as repealing or amending the previous law that it “contradicts”. For example, a parliament might have passed an act regulating liquor stores that has a provision that say they can’t open on Sundays. A later general trading law might have a provision that says all stores can trade on Sundays which would be construed as repealing the previous restriction even if it does not explicitly refer to it.

However, if a law is constitutionally entrenched this sort of thing is avoided. The recent law would not be effective to the extent that it was repugnant to the previous entrenched law unless it specificity dealt with the manner and form requirements necessary to amend the entrenched law.

Comment: The manner and form requirement would have to be worded very carefully to evade the possibility that a future parliament simply passes a one-line Act saying something along the lines of "Notwithstanding anything in any enactment, a simple majority in the House shall be sufficient to give a reading to any Bill".

Comment: ... and in the UK, the manner and form requirement would also need to defend against attempts to circumvent it using any of several Henry VIII clauses that allow a Statutory Instrument subject to a simple-majority affirmative resolution procedure to do anything that an Act of Parliament could do, or using the Church of England Assembly (Powers) Act 1919, which allows a Church Measure (again with a simple-majority affirmative resolution procedure) to do anything that an Act of Parliament could do.